# rescue data from partially overwritten ntfs partition

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery

I accidentally overwritten part of my ntfs partition with image of another partition using `dd if=diskimg of=/dev/sdaX`. I canceled it immediately, but unfortunately about 200MB was already written. I'm copying accessible data now, but some directories (most notably directory containing my desktop and documents) are empty. Is there a way to recover files in those directories that haven't actually been overwritten and are only inaccessible?

Comment: No; You already overwrote the data.

Comment: Not all of them, some are still intact. Unfortunately most of the data missing is the data I actually need whereas the data that's still intact is mostly old data I don't really need anymore.

Comment: You can try Recuva ==> https://www.piriform.com/docs/recuva/advanced-usage/running-recuva-from-a-usb-drive

Answer (score 0):

I did the exact same screwup as you did, overwriting the boot sector, the partition table, and a large portion of the data partition.

The good news is that I managed to salvage most of it. I didn't know of any tools to do this in linux, which would have been preferable, other than `dd` + `grep`, but a friend gave me a tip about [this tool](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm). It scans through a harddrive for data resembling files, ignoring *conveniences* such as a file allocation table, or even a partition table. It then allows you to extract said data either one and one manually, or in bulk automatically once detected.

The bad news is that it's not free software, but I can confirm that it works as advertised.

Comment: Sadly after reboot I can only see `System volume information` folder from linux. But I'll try again from windows.

Comment: After trying to recover a NTFS-Partition overwritten by a 400MB Linux-image, I tried recovery with testdisk and gpart to no avail. GetDataBack didn't give any results either, but with R-Studio I was able to recover the files (Not the original folder structure though, and a lot of useless files it appears to have made up from the fragments).